# How can I change one method of RestController containing image and VO to elegant code?

Tags: java

How can I change one method of RestController containing image and VO to elegant code?

This is the code inside the method named registCcinfo.

I'm currently learning coding, so I have no doubt that there will be some code that I don't know or need to fix at this stage.

Thank you for your opinion on how I can further improve my code.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/registCcInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> registCcInfo(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws AuthenticationException {
        logger.debug("/api/cc/registCcInfo POST, parameter MultipartHttpServletRequest : " + request);

        Map<String, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        String resultCd = "fail";
        String resultMsg = "Failed to register golf course information.";
        try {
            Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();

            Field[] fields = CcInfoVO.class.getDeclaredFields();

            CcInfoVO ccInfoVO = this.setValueToCcInfo(request, parameterNames, fields, new CcInfoVO());

            int result = ccInfoService.insertCcInfo(ccInfoVO);
            int courseCount = Integer.parseInt(ccInfoVO.getCcCourseCount());
            int holeCount;
            int count = 0;

            for (Object o: request.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
                String key = (String) o;
                map.put(key, request.getParameterMap().get(key));

            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= courseCount; i++) {

                CourseInfoVO pCourseInfoVO = new CourseInfoVO();
                pCourseInfoVO.setCcNo(ccInfoVO.getCcNo());
                pCourseInfoVO.setCourseName(Integer.toString(i));
                courseInfoService.insertCourseInfo(pCourseInfoVO);
                if (map.get("holeCount" + i) != null) {
                    String[] temp = (String[]) map.get("holeCount" + i);
                    holeCount = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
                    for (int j = 1; j <= holeCount; j++) {
                        count++;
                        HoleInfoVO PHoleInfoVO = new HoleInfoVO();
                        pHoleInfoVO.setCourseNo(pCourseInfoVO.getCourseNo());
                        pHoleInfoVO.setHoleNum(Integer.toString(j));
                        pHoleInfoVO.setRealHoleNo(Integer.toString(count));
                        holeInfoService.insertHoleInfo(pHoleInfoVO);
                    }
                }


            }


            int totalSize = ccInfoService.selectCcInfoCnt(ccInfoVO);

            if (result > 0) {
                resultCd = "success";
                resultMsg = "The golf course information registration was successful.";
                returnMap.put("totalSize", totalSize);
                returnMap.put("currentPage", ccInfoVO.getCurrentPage());
                returnMap.put("resultData", ccInfoService.selectCcInfoList(ccInfoVO));
            }
        } catch (LockedException e) {
            logger_error.error("Exception", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            logger_error.error("Exception", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            logger_error.error("IllegalArgumentException", iae);
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            logger_error.error("RuntimeException", re);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            logger_error.error("SQLException", se);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger_error.error("Exception", e);
        } finally {
            logger.debug("resultCd : " + resultCd);
            logger.debug("resultMsg : " + resultMsg);
            returnMap.put("resultCd", resultCd);
            returnMap.put("resultMsg", resultMsg);
        }
        return returnMap;
    }

private CcInfoVO setValueToCcInfo(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, Enumeration<String> parameterNames, Field[] fields, CcInfoVO ccInfoVO) {

        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String parameterName = parameterNames.nextElement();
            Field tempField = null;
            try {
                tempField = CcInfoVO.class.getDeclaredField(parameterName);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                continue; // If there is no field with that name, then
            }

            if (tempField != null) {
                tempField.setAccessible(true);
                String value = request.getParameter(parameterName);
                switch(tempField.getType().getTypeName()) {
                    case "int":
                        if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                            try {
                                tempField.set(ccInfoVO, Integer.parseInt(value));
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                                logger_error.error(e);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "java.lang.String":
                        try {
                            tempField.set(ccInfoVO, value);
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            logger_error.error(e);
}
                        break;
                    case "java.util.List":
                        if (value != null && !value.replaceAll(" ", "").isEmpty()) {
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>>() {
                            }.getType();
                            try {
                                tempField.set(ccInfoVO, gson.fromJson(value, type));
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                                logger_error.error(e);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        logger.debug("TypeName: " + tempField.getType().getTypeName() + ", value : " + value);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        String path = "ccImage/" + LocalDate.now() + "/";
        MultipartFile imageFile = request.getFile("file");
        if (imageFile != null && !(imageFile).isEmpty()) {
            ccInfoVO.setImagePath(path);
            ccInfoVO.setImageName("ccImage_" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".jpg");
            BufferedImage image = this.saveMultipartFile(path, ccInfoVO.getImageName(), imageFile);
            if (image != null) {
                ccInfoVO.setImageWidth(Integer.toString(image.getWidth()));
                ccInfoVO.setImageHeight(Integer.toString(image.getHeight()));
            }
        }
        return ccInfoVO;
    }

private BufferedImage saveMultipartFile(String path, String imageName, MultipartFile imageFile) {
        File pFile = new File(uploadRootPath + path);
        File cFile = new File(uploadRootPath + path + imageName);

        String fileExtension = imageName.substring(imageName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        if (!pFile.exists()) {
            pFile.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile.getInputStream());
            BufferedImage outputImage = CommonUtil.convertToBufferedImage(ImageIO.read(imageFile.getInputStream()), bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight());
            ImageIO.write(outputImage, fileExtension, cFile);

            return outputImage;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger_error.error(e);
        }
        return null;
    }



@Data
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CcInfoVO extends BaseVO {

//Fields
private int ccNo;
private String ccName;

private String ccControlYn;
private String ccManagerYn;
private String ccAddress;
private String ccTel;
private String ccX;
private String ccY;
private String ccNote;
private String isDeleted;


private String holeCount;
//image
private String imageName;
private String imagePath;
private String imageWidth;
private String imageHeight;


//input data
private String ccCourseCount;


}

Best Regards!
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Many things to refactoring... Try: 1 = look for `clean code` . 2 = you could extract your business implementation  to a service class, 3 = look for  how to use stream in `for`  java. 4 look for `builder pattern` to set values into your object. 5 = you could simplify handling exception grouping them in a specific one.. I think this is good start